# Sort by Date Descending in JS Search

Tags: 2013, javascript, search, keywordquery

I have a KeywordQuery in JavaScript.  The items returned are by date ascending.  How can I change this to date descending?

```
var keywordQuery = new SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery(clientContext);

var searchExecutor = new SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.SearchExecutor(clientContext);

keywordQuery.set_queryText(query); 

result = searchExecutor.executeQuery(keywordQuery);
```

Comment: Post relevant code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable sorting using below

```
keywordQuery.set_enableSorting(true); 
var sortproperties = keywordQuery.get_sortList();
sortproperties.add("Write", 1); //0 = Ascending
```